# Single value decomposition proof

Tags: linear-algebra

According to [French wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9composition_en_valeurs_singuli%C3%A8res) page of Singular Value Decomposition.

It states the following:

Let $M$ be a complex $m$ by $n$ matrix, then $M^*M$ is positive definite and hermitian. According to spectral theorem, there exists matrix $V$ such that

$$V^*M^*MV=\begin{bmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $D$ is a diagonal, positive definite, and have the same rank $r$ as $M$. By rewriting $V$ appropriately:

$$\begin{bmatrix} V_1^* \\ V_2^* \end{bmatrix}M^*M\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} V_1^*M^*MV_1 & V_1^*M^*MV_2 \\ V_2^*M^*MV_1 & V_2^*M^*MV_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $V_1$ is an $n$ by $r$ matrix of rank $r$ and $V_2$ is a matrix of size $n$ by $n-r$.

Thus, $V_1^*M^*MV_1=D$ and $MV_2=0$. We let

$$U_1=D^{-\frac12}V_1^*M^*,$$

then we have

$$U_1MV_1=D^{\frac12}$$

We complete $U_1$ to make it unitary.We choose $U_2$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} U_1 \\ U_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is unitary.

A calculation shows that:

$$\begin{bmatrix} U_1 \\ U_2 \end{bmatrix} M\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} D^{\frac12} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

**Question** : In the algebra proof of the SVD do you have any idea about why  $U_2MV_1=0$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $U_1MV_1=D^{\frac12},$ we have $M=U_1^*D^{\frac12}V_1^*$

\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}
U_1^* & U_2^*
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} D^{\frac12} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} V_1^* \\ V_2^*\end{bmatrix}&= U_1^*D^{\frac12}V_1^*=M
\end{align}

Hence \begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}
U_1 \\ U_2
\end{bmatrix}M\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix} D^{\frac12} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

From the lower left entry, we have $U_2MV_1=0$.

Comment: Thanks. So $U_2MV_1=U2U1^*D^{0.5}V1^*V1=0$ since $V1^*V1=0$. Is that true?  Ps: didn't you forget some element in your last line?

Comment: Sorry i meant U2U1=0!

Comment: made a typo during copy and paste, thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: ah, you mean $U_2^*U_1=0$? yup, that works too. btw, I edited your post so that others who have the same confusion as you can search for the post in the future if it is not deleted. Avoid link based posts and non-english posts if possible. Also, include thoughts and attempts whenever you can.